# The utilities I wrote don't work correctly + test cases

Tags: java, regex, spring, unit-testing, mockito

The utilities I wrote don't work correctly . So, I have 2 utilities that do different things :

1. ExtractPhoneNumber  - if the phone number is null then it returns null , if not null, the utility must remove from the number all characters except numbers( e.g. "+" or "-" or "()")
   If number starts with 0 then my utility write in variable phone , without 0 (012345 -> 12345)
   if length of phone number + country code number (of characters) < or > than the number allowed in the configuration it will return null
   if the number does not contain a country code then the country code added to phone number
2. ValidatePhoneNumber - if my string matches a regular expression, then I return true, if not, then false (if the phone number contains something other than "()" or "+" or "-" then the utility should return false)

I tried to explain how the utilities should work, also after I wrote them, I wrote tests that unfortunately do not pass, so I can not understand what my mistake is , I put 2 utilities and tests on them.

below are the utilities and tests for them :

```
public String extractPhoneNumber(String value) {
        String phone = StringUtils.trimToNull(value);

        if (phone == null)
            return null;

        phone = phone.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        if (phone.startsWith("0")) {
            phone = phone.substring(1);
        }

        if (phone.length() + configService.getPhoneCountryCode().length() < configService.getPhoneNumberLength()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (!phone.startsWith(configService.getPhoneCountryCode())) {
                if (phone.length() + configService.getPhoneCountryCode().length() > configService.getPhoneNumberLength()) {
                    return null;
                }

                phone = configService.getPhoneCountryCode() + phone;
            }
        }
        return phone;

    }
```

```
public final static Pattern VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN =
            Pattern.compile("[^0-9()\\-+]");

    public boolean validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Matcher matcher = VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(phoneNumber);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Tests :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqkMK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJiHR.jpg

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: @Stultuske yes, i debugged, but all looks okay, so i ask here

Comment: @AmirKerimov if all "looked okay", you wouldn't have to ask. that would mean your code did exactly what it's meant to do

Comment: @Stultuske so then i I am not using correctly debug

Comment: Your second method has a wrong regexp (it's a single character regexp now), and you could easily check what your first method returns to see whether it's working as you expect. You obviously haven't debugged the code, and probably don't know how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging). Don't answer "yes" to questions you don't understand, it makes you untrustworthy.

Comment: @Kayaman , 
I've used brakepoints on methods that use these methods, but most likely did something wrong. Thanks for the debugging guide.

Comment: Setting breakpoints won't fix your code magically. They're used to observe whether the code is doing what you expect it to do. Unless you're saying that the code works, but it's the tests that fail? The second regexp seems fine actually. since your logic doesn't care about the length but only about illegal characters.

Comment: @Kayaman , thank you for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: It's still not clear whether your business logic works and your tests fail or whether none of your code works (or if you don't know what works and what doesn't). If it's only about tests, maybe the answer given helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests are using `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` on instance variables that are not used in your tests.

The `@InjectMocks` on the `UtilService` is itself not a mock btw, and thus shouldn't be called `utilsServiceMock`, but simply `utilsService`. You will need to then mock the method return values of your `configService` (which is a mock) to return the data that you need to test the `utilsService`.

Your `UtilsService` should accept the `configService` as a constructor parameter. It's strange that you have a `utilsService` constructor that takes no parameters; it should not be the case.

Finally you need to use the instance variable `utilsService` in your tests, and not recreate the `UtilsService` object each time. As for your core logic, you should first fix the tests and then use them to find any bugs in your code (if there are any).